# Installing SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services after SQL Server 2005 is installed

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I need to install SSRS. Have alreay installed SQL Server.

Dosn't seem possible in Add/Remove programs and when I run the installation wizard again it seems to think its a fresh install. Whats the best appraoch for installation of SSRS after you have SQL Server installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start the setup and proceed to the point of instant selection and then you add features to it.

Answer (score 1):

Run the install disk.  Eventually it'll get to a spot where it asks if you want to install a new instance or to modify an existing one.  Select the instance you want to update.  It'll then bring you to a list of all the current installed components and it'll let you select new components to install.

If you get SSRS installed and need help setting it up, let me know and i'll see if i can help.